# more/less button for text using angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular

Currently, I added more/less button using Jquery ([jsfiddle.net/ax2UR/1](http://jsfiddle.net/ax2UR/1)). But now I need to do it using angular. If you know any tutorial, please send the link.

```
<ul *ngFor="let room of roomDetail; let i = index">
 <li>
    RoomName : {{room.details}} <button>More/Less </button>
 </li>
```

Above is sample data for my work. I think you can understand my question

Comment: Hello gihankumara you can find some nice guides at https://angular.io/start. Best of luck.

Comment: By looking at your code, you have added the More/Less buttons dynamically using angular *ngFor directive. This seems correct where you have not used JQuery.